# How to find the resource id for a textfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, app-store, google-play-console, resource-id, prelaunch

I would like to register the test account credentials for the Pre-launch report in Google Play. In addition to the username and password, I need to provide resource IDs.

I would like to know how I could obtain the resource ID in a Flutter project to add it to the Pre-launch report.

[Google Play Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZf3S.png)

Grateful for any help out there !

Comment: Hi Sandra, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Try use widget key. Example :

```dart
TextFormField(
  key: const Key('username'),
  controller: controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: label,
    suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
    filled: true,
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red[400],
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 13,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Also you can test in Firebase test lab to confirm does it work or not before actually submiting your app in goog

Answer (score 0):

You can give controller name as resource name

code ->

```
TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                keyboardType: inputType ?? TextInputType.name,
                obscureText: isObSecure ?? false,
                autofocus: autoFocus ?? false,
                onTap: onTap,
                
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: hint,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.onSurfaceColor.withOpacity(.4),
                  ),
                  // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                ),
              ),
```

[image: Image from google play console]